# How do I find the electric field components from an FDTD simulation using GPAW?

Tags: gpaw, finite-difference-time-domain

I have been following the FDTD tutorials for GPAW, and have been able to determine how to print the electric field strength (magnitude), but not the components of the electric field. How would I do this?

Thank you,
Jason Gray

The tutorials I am following are: [this one](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/gpaw/documentation/electrodynamics/qsfdtd.html#advanced-example-near-field-enhancement) for the classical case and [this one](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/gpaw/documentation/electrodynamics/hybridscheme.html) for the hybrid quantum/classical scheme.

Comment: +1. Welcome to the site and thank you so much for contributing your question here! We hope to see much more of you in the future !!!!! We also have a GPAW chat room (which is still new, so there's not a lot of chat going on yet). Please type "hello" to us at least once so that we know you're interested in GPAW! https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112878/gpaw

Comment: This might also be related, and I'm posting it here since the [tag:finite-difference-time-domain] tag didn't exist before! https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2380/5

Comment: Hi! It would nice if you could add in links to the tutorials you've followed to learn the software in case its useful to other users.

Comment: I just added links to the tutorials. Good call!

Comment: @JasonMGray If you can please put the part of the problem that you figured out, into the answer, then delete this comment, that would be great. As you gain more experience here you'll see what comments are really for.

Comment: @JasonMGray Please answer your own post with that information so it can be preserved, comments should not be considered permanent.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the induced field components from an induced field object. If you call your induced field object ind, then you can get the Fourier transform of the field components by accessing ind.Fef_wvg. Adding the initial kick strength to this and taking the magnitude you can get the total electric field. Comparing the total electric field magnitude to the field enhancement (ind.Ffe_wg) times the initial field magnitude you should get the same value.